How to work with signs and slots with QTablewidget?
I'm creating a plugin and I want to check my GUI.
I want to check if the QTableWidget is filled in any of its items and if this is true, enable the button box. I did something similar with LineEdit with the following code:
self.TXT_ID.textChanged.connect(self.id_changed)  

    def id_changed(self):
        """Função para verificar se o LineEdit do ID da curva foi preenchido"""
        if self.TXT_ID.text():
            self.button_box.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.button_box.setEnabled(False)

Is there any way to do this check for the QTableWidget?

The QTableWidget has a signal itemChanged , see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#signals and https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged . You can probably connect it the same way you do for your textbox.

itemChanged signal is only emitted when the data of an item is changed. It is not emitted e.g. when an item is deleted, so can't really be used to track the amount of items. Maybe I am missing something here, but I am not sure how this answer is useful for the question.

My reasoning was that I thought the table is maybe an options table and the user can fill in option values for predefined options. That way the full structure is static and the user only changes values. But yes, of course itemChanged fires only on item change, as rowsInserted and rowsRemoved fire only on insertion or removal. You have to pick the right signal for your usecase. There are a number of signals mentioned in the linked documentation.

Using the two signals rowsInserted and rowsRemoved of the underlying item model, you can detect whenever the amount of items in the table changes and then enable/disable the button box accordingly.

self.table_widget.model().rowsInserted.connect(self.on_items_changed)
self.table_widget.model().rowsRemoved.connect(self.on_items_changed)

def on_items_changed(self):
    if self.table_widget.rowCount() > 0: # check if any items are in the table
        self.button_box.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        self.button_box.setEnabled(False)


